# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask' even when I installed flask

Tags: python, flask, web, module, backend

I am a begineer and wanted to try flask using VScode, but for some reason VScode doesnt recognize flask even though it's already installed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WC4KS.png)

I made some test like pip list and I confirmed that I have flask installed. I changed the insterprer and it didn't work. When I hover "flask", VScode recognizes it. Why?

Comment: Use ```pip install flask``` in terminal then try.

Comment: I used that to install it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Perhaps the interpreter you are using is not the same where flask is installed?
2. By looking at your screenshot, it doesn't look like the environment is activated. Try activating the environment before running the command. When you select the interpreter in VS Code (check [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_working-with-python-interpreters)), usually the environment is automatically activated when running the code. If using the base environment, you should see `(base) PS C:\Users\...` instead of `PS C:\Users\...` in the terminal.
3. Also, is there a reason for using the -u parameter?